# the program is very slow, why? in C#

Tags: c#, performance, excel

i'm using this code to export an excel wuth 256 rows at the moment (later i need 256k of rows), but the program is very slow compare to java,
i read a folder with all text files in it, then i read all lines in each file, i look for a letter, and if i see it, i add the line to the excel file

what is the problem at my program?

```
       private void Create_Excel_File_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressBarTimer.Start();

            String[] Coulmn_Head =  {"סוג פעולה","    נקלט בשעה"};

        int Coulmn = 1, Row = 1;
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        for (Coulmn=1; Coulmn <=Coulmn_Head.Length; Coulmn++)
        {

            xlWorkSheet.Cells[Row, Coulmn] = Coulmn_Head[Coulmn - 1];
            xlWorkSheet.Columns[Coulmn].AutoFit();
        }
        Coulmn = 1;
        Row++;
        int CountErrors = 0;
        string[] Files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(SourceFolderText.Text, "*.txt");


        for (int i = 0; i < Files.Length; i++)
        {
            string line;
            System.IO.StreamReader File_Now = new System.IO.StreamReader(Files[i]);
            while ((line = File_Now.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < line.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (line[j] >= 'א' && line[j] <= 'ת')
                    {
                        string[] words = line.Split('|');
                        foreach (string word in words)
                        {
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[Row, Coulmn++] = word;
                        }
                        Coulmn = 1;
                        Row++;
                        j = line.Length;
                        CountErrors++;

                    }


                }

            }
            File_Now.Close();
        }


        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(TargetFolderText.Text + "\\" + TargetFIleText.Text + ".xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);

        MessageBox.Show(CountErrors + " Errors Found");


    }
```

Comment: Don't access one cell at a time. Operate on ranges.

Comment: this question should be on code-review

Comment: Your second `for` loop contains too many nested blocks in my opinion. I don't really know the Excel libraries for .NET, but surely they must provide more appropriate methods and classes for this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, what do you offer?

Comment: What do you mean. Stop accessing one cell at a time, and instead access a range of cells.

Comment: how can i put all words, in all cells, without access one cell at time?

Comment: it's too late to answer now  but yeah... Range is a 2D array therefore you can store data in a 2D array and export it to a Range object very easily without loops ... ie. `myRange.set_Value(Type.Missing, array2D)`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, i did it and it works. thank you, you can put it as an answer and i will edit it and put my code.

Comment: I don't think we need any code. There exists plenty already. I cannot add an answer since the question has been closed for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Excel app takes significant time to initialize, and you instantiate it every time when handler is triggered (`Create_Excel_File_Click`).

So you better create one global application-wide Excel instance, so the host app will be freezed only once, at startup.

```
public class ExcelComponent
{
    private static Excel.Application _app;
    public static App
    {
        get
        {
            if (_app == null)
                _app = new Excel.Application();
            return _app;
        }
    }
}

private void Create_Excel_File_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Application xlApp = ExcelComponent.App;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    // etc.
}
```